# Why is myVar undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

When I get my socket event `drawMouse` & my `draw()` function is called `myVar` is undefined. **Why can't I access `this.myVar` from within the socket.on callback?**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  myVar:string;

  constructor(){
    this.socket = io("http://localhost:4300");
    this.myVar = "hello"

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.socket.on('drawMouse', function(data){
          this.draw(data)
      })
  }

  draw(){
    //this variable is undefined
    console.log(this.myVar);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `draw` is actually called? That seems unlikely.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` inside the socket callback is not refering to the component.

Try:

```
 this.socket.on('drawMouse', (data)=>{
          this.draw(data)
      })
```

Comment: @FelixKling oh I didn't realize that and how so? :D

Comment: No idea ;) Maybe I'm misinterpreting the text.

Comment: @echonax that worked.  I guess it's due to trying to using es6 scoping, but not using the new function syntax right?

Comment: @JustinYoung exactly. We were a little confused though whether you actually succeeded in calling the method or not.

Comment: @echonax Yeah it was calling the method, but when I logged out the value of myVar within the method call it was undefined.  Guess it was just getting the lines crossed.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JustinYoung: *"Yeah it was calling the method"* But that's impossible given your original code. Inside the callback, `this` refers to `window` (or `undefined`), not the instance.